# $('[data-toggle="popover"]') selects nothing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have page, contents for DIV is filled by .post request, with items: `<div data-toggle="popover" ....><a><img></a></div>`, this part works fine. but when i try afterwards activate popover by selecting [data-toggle="popover"] jquery returns "[]" any ideas what am i doing wrong? (code is cutted just to show main idea).

```
<script>
    function updateGallery() {

        $.post('/images/?action=list', '', function (data) {

            for (var item in data.result) {

                gallery_dom += '
<div data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="'+ item.size +'">'+
'<a class="thumbnail">'+
'<img id="gal-' + item.id + '" class="image" big="'+item._big+'" src="' + item._src + '"></a></div>';

                } // for

$('#gallery-list').empty();
$('#gallery-list').html(gallery_dom);
}

}

</script>

<div id="gallery-list"></div>


<script>
$(function(){

updateGallery();

console.log($('[data-toggle="popover"]));
</script>
```

Comment: AJAX requests are asynchronous. Your console.log is executed prior to your .post() request completing.

Comment: yep. you're right.. if i move it inside .post() it works right.. how i have to track .post completion right if i have run such query from other part of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the `popover` within the ajax `success` callback. That's when you can be sure that the new content has been added to the DOM. Maybe right after `$('#gallery-list').html(gallery_dom);` inside the `updateGallery()` functon.

Try putting `console.log($('[data-toggle="popover"]);` right after that line.

Comment: you should fix `nsole.log` to `console.log` I can't because it is only a few characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether the Gallery has been updated correctly, you can use a temporary HTML element (DIV, button, etc.) and attach an event handler to it. For instance, you could use the following HTML

```
<div id="gallery-list"></div>
<div id="testGallery">Click here to test Gallery</div>
```

and use this JS to allow the console to log results correctly (once you see that the Gallery has updated).

```
$('#testGallery').click(function(){
            console.log($('[data-toggle="popover"]'));    
});
```

Alternatively, you could use a global flag (not my favorite tool but it works) or some other mechanism to let your code know that the Gallery has been updated. Before sending the AJAX request, you set the flag to "not updated" and when it's done ("done" callback), you set it back to "updated".

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to **pass a function as parameter** :

---

**1° step:** *What function do you want do execute after $.post()?*

```
function afterPost() {
    console.log( $('[data-toggle="popover"]') );
}
```

---

**2° step:** *Reference it as parameter in your function and call it after $.post():*

```
function updateGallery( callback ) {
    $.post('/images/?action=list', '', function (data) {
         /*
             ...
         */
         callback();
    }
}
```

---

**3° step, finally:** *Use it!*

```
$(function(){
    updateGallery( afterPost );
})
```

---

** Hope it helps! **